# when the dropdown value changed Price Also change Want Price and size in Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Want to add rows runtime in Tabel innerHTML on top when the dropdown value changed Price Also change Want Price and size in Table.just like amazone :

[https://www.amazon.com/Calvin-Klein-Womens-Printed-Sleeve/dp/B07621LRN6/ref=br_asw_pdt-8?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=HWQ3TASK6QW286D8CV65&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=913206c3-eb35-4cfe-a4c8-6c0b0a5ce93b&pf_rd_i=desktop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07621LRN6)

Select Size Small,Large,Xl,XLL

Every one have different prices i want to add tabel on top of site that have both size plus in one row if drop down have four values then four times price change and create four rows
I am trying this using Async function 
Code is below:

```
function() {
function fireEvent(element, event) {
    if (document.createEventObject) {
        var evt = document.createEventObject();
        return element.fireEvent('on'+event, evt);
    } else {
        var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        evt.initEvent(event, true, true);
        return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}

var prices = [];
var inclSizes = [];
var siteURLs = [];


var createTable = () => {
    var newTable="<table>";
    siteURLs.forEach(function(wid,i){
        var line="<tr>";
        line+="<td>"+siteURLs[i]+"</td>";
        line+="<td>"+inclSizes[i]+"</td>";
        line+="<td>"+inclSizes[i]+"</td>";

        line+="</tr>";
        newTable+=line;
    });
    newTable+="</table>";
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', newTable);
    return true;
};

var getData = ({cushionPromiseResolve,inclSize}) => {
    var prices = document.querySelector('span[id="priceblock_ourprice"]');
    siteURLs.push('https://www.amazon.com/');
    inclSize?inclSizes.push(inclSize):inclSizes('N/A')
    prices ? prices.push(prices.textContent) : prices.push('N/A');

    if (cushionPromiseResolve) {
        cushionPromiseResolve();
    }
};

async function sizeVariations() {
    var sizeVariations = document.querySelector('span[id="dropdown_selected_size_name"] span[class="a-dropdown-prompt"]');
        if (sizeVariations.textContent=== 'Select') {
            for (var i=0; i < sizeVariations.options.length; i++) {
                if (sizeVariations.options[i].value === '') {
                    getData({ inclSize: 'False'});
                    continue;
                }
                sizeVariations.selectedIndex = i;
                fireEvent(sizeVariations, 'change');
                await new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                 setTimeout(function() {
                     getData({cushionPromiseResolve: resolve, inclSize: 'True'});
                 }, 1500);
                });
            }
        }

    return createTable();
}

return sizeVariations();
```

}